# Virtual field AND real field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

Is it possible to have a virtual field that is also a field in a model?

```
var exampleSchema = new Schema({
      name : {type: String, required: true}
      slug:: {type: String}
});


exampleSchema.virtual('slug').get(function() {

    if(this.slug && this.slug.length){
        return this.slug;
    }

    return this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

If slug is set I want to return the slug. If not, I want to return a computed value from name.

I don't want to use a static method, it needs to be a part of the result when pulled a record.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom getter function and return the value if it exists, or the computed value if it doesn't.

```
var exampleSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
    slug: {
        type: String,
        get: function(value) {
            if (value) {
                return value;
            } else {
                return this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
            }
        }
    }
});
```